# How to reference APIs? (BibTeX preferred)

Tags: bibtex

How to reference this kind of "literature" (APIs):

- Example 1: Google AppEngine DataStore API v1.7.0 http://...
- Example 2: JavaMail API v1.4.5 http://...

I normally use BibTeX, but are these just "plain URLs" in practice?

Where does one get BibTex for these? For RFCs I use a nightly export/convert service that pinches them from IETF, for ISBNs on Amazon I use a web service which does the same... for APIs, is there a typical way to do this?

What about Java Specification Requests (JSRs)?

Comment: Are you searching for an export tool for API references or are you asking how to properly typeset them or how to fill in BibTeX entries for API references? If it's the latter, I have to say that I found the BibLaTeX `online` entry type much more convincing than what standard BibTeX provides.

Comment: Question is: how to fill in BibTeX entries for API references?

Comment: @Robottinosino: I think the filling of a BibTeX entry isn't the issue. First of all you have to know the result. Do you know how should the result look like? Without this information the question is off topic for me and should be closed.

Comment: `Google (2012), `Google App Engine Datastore Java API'. [Accessed: June 2012]. URL: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/`

Comment: @Robottinosino: I got no notification of your comment. You can response to a person by `@<name>`. Which bibliographystyle do you use? If we have all information we can provide a solution.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how the output should look, rather than the technical detail of how to achieve this in TeX.